# Flex Mobile: Different filenames for Android/iOS

Tags: android, ios, apache-flex, mobile

I'm creating an app to deploy for iOS and Android and I'd like to give them slightly different filenames (need to add a space so that name displays on two lines on Android). Is there a way for me to define this in the app.xml without having to change it each time I export?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a few ways to do this.  One would be to use a build script like Maven or Ant to build it for you and specify a different name in the app.xml for both the Android and iOS version.  There might be a way to do this within Flash Builder (which I assume you're using) by using some kind of environment variable.

Another way to do this would be to create 2 different projects, one for Android and one for iOS, then create a "common" library between the two where most of the code lies.  I prefer this approach as I've noticed some inconsistencies where the code behaves differently in different OS'.  By doing this approach, you can circumvent those edge cases, like the one you're currently having.

Comment: +1 from me.  In Flash Builder I believe he could create two different main applications in the same project, which would then have different app.xml files which he could use to change the name.